# jQuery .load() redirecting page when triggered

Tags: jquery, redirect

I've been struggling with this for far too many hours and hoping you guys can point out if I'm doing something wrong.

I have a wordpress page that loaded videos from JSON feed using php, but it loads too slow for my liking and I wanted to run the php scripts after the page loaded using jquery.

I tested it several times and it works as expected when I test on a blank page, but when I'm trying to load it right into a wordpress template, it's oddly redirecting.

So, here is the basic jquery I'm using to load:

```
<script type="text/javascript">                                   
        $(document).ready( function() { 
            setTimeout( function() { 
                $('#main-video-list').html('').load('../test.php'); 
            }, 4000); 
        }); 
    </script>
```

The timeout is just to give it some wait time so I can easily see it run after some other things load.  The issue I can't seem to find a way around is that everytime this function triggers, it actually redirects the entire window to the url being loaded, in this case test.php.

It doesn't seem to be related to the script being sent in, because if I change test.php to include just a simple paragraph of text, it acts the same way.

(Update: it preserves the url of the previous page, but all elements are gone. It results in a blank page with only the stuff loaded from test.php)

Has anyone experienced this?  I cannot find anything online where people are having the same issue, but I just cannot put my finger on what is causing it either.

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated!

(edited to update code based on comment from @nnnnn)

Comment: have you tried using absloute url?

Comment: I suspect something wrong with the way you have the HTML set up.

Comment: Hi charlietfl, I did try an absolute url first and it didn't work.  I figured perhaps the http:// in it had something to do so changed to relative.

Comment: As an aside, you know you can say `$('#main-video-list').html("").load('../test.php')` rather than having a separate call to `document.getElementById()` on the same element?

Comment: @Barmar, how would that be?  I've got a div with the id 'main-video-list'.  The div clears properly from the innerHTML = ''; but then it redirects.

Comment: When you say it redirects, do you mean you actually see `test.php` in the browser's location bar?

Comment: @nnnnn, I didn't know that - thanks for the tip!  I can't seem to find a common reason (headers/encoding/ect.) why it might act this way.  The exact same code works on the same host outside the wordpress install/template.  I've worked plenty with wordpress templates and never had anything like this happen - im just not sure what to troubleshoot anymore.

Comment: @Barmar, that's a great question.  Actually it preserves the url of the previous page, but all elements are gone.  It results in a blank page with only the stuff loaded from test.php

Comment: It seems like it's getting inserted into a DIV that contains the whole page, instead of the DIV you're expecting. That's why I think there's a problem with the HTML.

Comment: I figured out it was actually something to do with test.php.  I was loading in a <script> and it's redirecting because of that.  I've narrowed it down and realize it is that line.  It's a third party script so I can't edit what's on the other end, but is there a way to load scripts through this method without getting that reaction?

Comment: I've figured this out I belive.  Found a way to pull in a dynamic attribute from the php page, then build the script on the other side.  Thanks for everyones help!

Comment: Turns out the script itself is wierd.  For example, when I append the script similar to <script>something.something()</script> it always does that same issue.  Very confusing and frustrating, but must be an issue with the third-party script.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem. Turned out that the HTML returned from the .load() call had a <script> tag inside it, that was doing a document.write(...). I removed this <script> and the problem went away. Maybe this is your issue as well.